# Query to update and delete records in two different tables

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I want to write a query that deletes a record from a table and updates a record in anther one. This is my query:

```
DELETE FROM borrowed_books a WHERE a.id = '$id'  
            AND
             UPDATE books b SET b.nr_copies=b.nr_copies+1 where 
b.id_book=a.id_book
```

The error in console says:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version`

I am using mySQL and XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do two action in a query

you must use two query

```
DELETE FROM borrowed_books a WHERE a.id = '$id' 
; 

UPDATE books b 
INNER JOIN borrowed_books a 
SET b.nr_copies=b.nr_copies+1 
where b.id_book=a.id_book 
and a.id = '$id' 
;
```

using update with join

eventually you can  check for your mysql driver for multiple query  in a command

Comment: Put those in a transaction!